# Relationship between ideals of rings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, ring-homomorphism

Asumming that we have two rings $R$ and $S$ and an onto (surjective) homomorphism $\alpha :R\rightarrow S$.

I am interested in knowing what relationships exists between the ideals of $R$ and the ideals of $S$?

One such relationship I can think off (which I am not sure is true) is:

$\alpha(rR) = \alpha(r)S$

What is the most general way to express the relationships by $\alpha$ in between the ideals of the two rings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your relation is correct if the homomorphism is surjective. Lore gennerally (with the same hypothesis), the ideals in $S$ correspond bijectively to the ideals of $R$ which contain $\ker\alpha$.

Comment: let me see if I understood correctly. You are saying that if $I \subseteq R$ and ker $(\alpha) \subseteq I$ then there is a bijection in between all  of these ideals and the ideals of $S$. Which would imply that the Ideals of $R$ not containing the kernel would be mapped arbitrarily to ideals in $S$. Correct?

Comment: An ideal $J$ not (necessarily) containing $\ker\alpha$ is mapped to $(J+\ker\alpha)/\ker\alpha$.